# GET value of <td> With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

In my Checkout page, i have table which is display products where customer want to buy and than i want get value of each `<td>` and save it into database, but i dont know what did i wrong, i also get class to each `<td>`, but it couldn't get value of `<td>` and than when i check DB i can see row is inserted but contains null value. Can anyone please help me or point me into the right direction :)

This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping Checkout</h1>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th class="text-xs-right">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="output"> </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block placeorder" value="PlaceOrder">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //Display Products in Checkout list
        function myfunction() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:xxx/api/Values/ProdukterudID" + params,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (values) {
                    var total = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        value = values[i]
                        if (value != null) {
                            var stotal = localStorage.getItem("prod_" + value.ProductID) * value.ProductPrice;
                            total += stotal;

                           //here i defined <td> with class
                            holderHTML += '<tr><td class="Qty">' + localStorage.getItem("prod_" + value.ProductID) + '</td><td class="ProductName"> ' + value.ProductName + '</td><td> ' + formatMoney(value.ProductPrice) + ' </td><td class="Subtotal" class="text-xs-right"> ' + formatMoney(stotal) + '</td></tr>'
                        }

                    }

                    $('#output').html(holderHTML);
                },
            })
        }

        myfunction();

       //Button click save into database
            $(".placeorder").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                var model = {
                    Qty: tr.find(".Qty").text(),
                    Subtotal: tr.find(".Subtotal").text(),
                    ProductName: tr.find(".ProductName").text(),
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "http://localhost:xxx/api/Values/PlaceOrder",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        Qty: model.Qty,
                        Subtotal: model.Subtotal,
                        ProductName: model.ProductName,
                        Email: localStorage.getItem("Email")
                    },
                    success: function (run) {

                        if (run)
                        {
                            console.log("Ok");
                        }

                        else {
                            console.log("error");
                        }                   
                    }

                });
            });
     });
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/Values/PlaceOrder")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PlaceOrder() {

    DateTime CreatedAt = DateTime.Today;
    CustomerOrdersVM model = new CustomerOrdersVM();

    var SaveOrdre = new CustomerOrders
    {
        Qty = model.Qty,
        Email = model.Email,
        ProductName = model.ProductName,
        Subtotal = model.Subtotal,
        CreatedAt = CreatedAt,
    };

    db.CustomerOrders.Add(SaveOrdre);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the placeholder button in the same TR as the row that contains the data being processed?  It didn't appear so in the dynamic markup sample you are adding.

```
$(".placeorder").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var tr = $(this).closest("tr"); // button in same TR as data cell?

    var model = {  Qty: tr.find(".Qty").text(), .. } // same row as button?
```

Comment: no it isn't :) how can i fix it? would you please guide me :)

Comment: When the user clicks place order, essentially you want to loop through all of the rows for the products the user added to the cart, and process each one?  Or will the table with the data always have one row?

Comment: yes , i want when user click on button take data from each row and save it into data base